# How to apply advanced css with function to body except one element

Tags: css, html

I am working with an HTML5 template, except I bumped into this CSS property that has some functions like `is-loading`, `is-switching`:

```
body.is-loading *, body.is-loading *:before, body.is-loading *:after, body.is-switching *, body.is-switching *:before, body.is-switching *:after {
            -ms-animation: none !important;
            animation: none !important;
            transition: none !important;
            transition-delay: none !important;
        }
```

I can't delete it because my template won't work, basically, it disables the animation and transition at the beginning (when it's loading) but since I have a loading div with id `loading` hence it won't work because the animations of all body have been disabled.

Based on the information I found in the internet, I tried using `not()` to apply the CSS to everything except my Id `loading` as follows, but unfortunately it didn't work:

```
body.is-loading *:not(#loading), body.is-loading *:not(#loading):before, body.is-loading *:not(#loading):after, body.is-switching *:not(#loading), body.is-switching *:not(#loading):before, body.is-switching *:not(#loading):after {
        -ms-animation: none !important;
        animation: none !important;
        transition: none !important;
        transition-delay: none !important;
    }
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide the HTML as well?

Comment: this is the template: https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/dimension/

Comment: To clarify, do you want animation to work on your `#loading` element, or on all other elements?

Comment: Can't you just remove the !important tags and then overwrite loading below?

Comment: without that css  code in `body` the animation of `loading` works, so I want to somehow bypass that css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't modify the body tag but can add new css, you can have increased specificity by adding your code below the body css tag.

```css
body.is-loading *,
body.is-loading *:before,
body.is-loading *:after,
body.is-switching *,
body.is-switching *:before,
body.is-switching *:after {
  -ms-animation: none !important;
  animation: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
  transition-delay: none !important;
}

#loading {
  -ms-animation: all ease-in-out 0.3s !important;
  animation: all ease-in-out 0.3s !important;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s !important;
  transition-delay: all ease-in-out 0.3s !important;
}
```